# distribute multiple versions of Android app to internal testers

Tags: android, google-play-console

Internal testers want to test multiple versions of our Android app, but Google Play internal track provides only one app available at a time.

Google's [documentation](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en) describes how the Google Play app determines which *single* version will appear. (To see this, expand the subsection entitled "Version code requirements" in the section titled, "Version codes & testing track statuses")

TestFlight has this capability: [screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/r1ww6ht2wxm38wa/IMG_3326.PNG?dl=0), so I'd imagine there would have to be an easy way to do this in Google Play as well.

Comment: Are you asking for AB tests?  If so, https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6227309?hl=en.  If you're asking for different versions for internal testers and to allow the to choose which one, then sideloading rather than the Play Store is probably more appropriate.

Comment: @GabeSechan, no, not AB testing, but rather, full-on QA testing.  Maybe you're right about sideloading - it works for APK's (unlike iOS IPA's).  In that case, do you put links to APK's up on an intranet page?  Seems a bit crude in 2019.

Comment: Dropbox, Google drive, or the like works too. Grab the file, and then trap to install

Comment: I have shared APK's that way with other devs, but it's a bit awkward for green testers.  These app testers are internal employees from sales, marketing, etc in a corporate environment.

Comment: The way I work around this issue is to create a closed test track for each version of our app.  But since all test tracks use the same opt-in URL, each time a tester wants to switch versions, I have to manually remove user from one test track, and add them to another.